# Cannot remove set screw in deadbolt thumb turn

Tags: doors, screws, lock, deadbolt

I'm trying to remove the thumb turn on my door. There appears to be a set screw that's preventing the knob from coming off. I believe the manufacturer of the lock is Lawrence Hardware.

I have tried every hex wrench I have (including those in my iFixit kit: https://canada.ifixit.com/products/mako-driver-kit-64-precision-bits). Everything just seems to freely spin.

Does anyone know what type of screw head I'm dealing with here? Is it a security bit of some sort?

Thank you in advance for the help!

[image: Set screw in thumb turn]

Comment: Unless there is another hole opposite to that, maybe it is a pin, I think the only wrench for removing it is a drill and bit.  It might have had a hex socket at one time in the past, but not anymore.  If you do not want to use a drill, an epoxy glue might hold a hex key in it long enough to remove.  50/50 chance if you wait till complete set of the glue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I may try the epoxy approach..

Comment: I'm sure it's a hex keyed screw.  Might be a metric size.  Also, I just removed the door know on one of my doors and, though I'm not certain, it may have been reverse threaded.  So when I thought I was trying to remove the screw, I was really over tightening it.  Luckily I did not destroy the head in the process.

Comment: If this is a thumb turn on a deadbolt, why are you removing it?

Comment: If you do use an epoxy, everything(hole and key) needs to cleaned of all paint/oil/dirt.  The hex key will need to be held solid to the hole for maybe hours, before trying, for best results.  A drill will take a minute or two.  Will depend if this for replacement or repair.  If replacement, a nice big hammer sometimes works as well as a drill, but faster.

Comment: @SteveSh could be *imperial* size, since the OP says none of the bits in his kit (which is metric) work.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt that's a setscrew. More likely it's a spring retainer. Try pressing it in with the tip of a pointed object such as a nail (or one of those hex wrenches); if it moves, hold it depressed while pulling the knob off.

Answer (score 0):

If you think it is a screw (I don't), you can try using a screw extractor tool.

[image: screw]

Comment: Sometimes just the left-rotation drilling will walk the troublesome fastener out, but the extraction component may indeed be needed.

Comment: Ah interesting! If it isn't a screw, what would it be? I did try an awl with some pressure while pulling outwards on the thumbturn but it didn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: Looks like a crimp factory made to keep the pieces together and never anticipated to be taken apart.